# Using prefixes to display entities from an rdflib graph

Tags: python, prefix, rdflib

I'm using rdflib to load an RDF graph into a Python scrpit
I would like to print a list of subjects using the defined prefixes
I doesn't find any method to apply the prefixes.
My code

```
import rdflib
filepath = "... my file path ..."
gs = rdflib.Graph()
gs.bind('qs', "http://qs.org/")
gs.bind('foaf',"http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/")
gs.parse(filepath,format="nt")
mdstr = ""
for subject in gs.subjects():
    mdstr += str(subject) +"\n"
print(mdstr)
```

I get, for example
http://qs.org/s12095
in place of
qs:s12095

Comment: It seems that these bindings are used only in full graph serialization. Can't find any ready to use function, try `mdstr += ('_:' + subject if isinstance(subject, rdflib.BNode) else  gs.namespace_manager.normalizeUri(subject)) + '\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

[Relevant rdflib documentation](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/namespaces_and_bindings.html). The prefixes in a graph are stored in its `NamespaceManager` object. To get rdflib to print the prefixes instead of the complete IRI, you can call its method `.n3(graph.namespace_manager)`. So in your case, you can do:

```
from rdflib import Namespace
from rdflib.namespace import NamespaceManager

# bind namespace to the graph or its namespace manager
graph.bind('qs', Namespace('http://qs.org/'))

# assuming entity is IRI http://qs.org/s12095
print(entity) # --> http://qs.org/s12095
print(entity.n3(graph.namespace_manager)) # --> qs:s12095
```